# Using items from List<string> in SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

Ok, I have a list that consists of a bunch of values from a sql query, that part works fine. What I want to do is use the items in that list to tell another query what to look for. So, what it is saying is that, it should return all columns from CMMReports where PartNumber is like %listItem1..2...3%, Any advice?

```
List<string> ImportedParts = GetImportedPartNumbers();

string query = "SELECT * FROM CMMReports WHERE (RacfId IS NULL OR RacfId = '') AND (FilePath NOT LIKE '%js91162%') AND PartNumber LIKE %" + ImportedParts + "% ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC;";
```

Comment: Are you looking to match EVERY item in the list in a single record? or ANY item in the list?

Comment: You should start by at least doing a parameterized SQL query so you don't hit with a SQL injection attack.

Comment: so if you already have a list of existing part numbers why are you using LIKE?  LIKE is when you want to match a portion of the string:

Like "%an" finds every record that ENDS in AN
LIKE "an%" finds every record that STARTS in AN
LIKE "%an%" finds every record that CONTAINS AN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I condone this as you should be using parameterized queries. However, this should work:

```
StringBuilder partNumbers = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string queryValue in ImportedParts)
{
    string q = "PartNumber LIKE '%" + queryValue + "%'";
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(partNumbers.ToString())
    {
       partNumbers.Append(q);
    }
    else
    {
       partNumbers.Append(" OR " + q);
    }
}

string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM CMMReports WHERE (RacfId IS NULL OR RacfId = '') " +
           "AND (FilePath NOT LIKE '%js91162%') AND ({0}) " +
           "ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC;", partNumbers.ToString());
```

Comment: This is close to what i need, however it gives me  AND PartNumber LIKE value1 AND PartNumber LIKE value2 AND PartNumber LIKE value3, what i need is AND PartNumber like value1 OR PartNumber like value2 OR PartNumber like value3.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you should get the idea:

```
List<string> ImportedParts = GetImportedPartNumbers(); 

SqlCommand cmd = myConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM CMMReports WHERE (RacfId IS NULL OR RacfId = '') AND (FilePath NOT LIKE '%js91162%') AND (";

int i = 0;
foreach (string part in ImportedParts) {
    cmd.AddParameterWithValue("@param" + i.ToString(), "%" + part + "%");
    if (i != 0) cmd.CommandText += " OR"
    cmd.CommandText += " PartNumber LIKE @param" + i.ToString();
    i++;
}

cmd.CommandText += ") ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC;";
```

This solution uses a parameterized query instead of just appending strings in the SQL, which is considered a potential security risk.

Answer (score 0):

You might look up the IN clouse for SQL that way you get the answer for the parts that SQL Server can find in the database. Using WHERE x = y for all the items means that if one item can't be found the whole query returns nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider doing this in a stored procedure and passing in your list as an `Xml` parameter.

See the following article for more info on using Xml parameters in a stored proc:

[Passing lists to SQL Server 2005 with XML Parameters - By Jon Galloway](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx)

Form there you can easily use your list data inside your stored proc using the Xml syntax and treat it almost as another table of data.